# Find the highest minimum difference of a number from a given range

Tags: algorithm, math, numbers, time-complexity

Say I have an array of N numbers {A1, A2, ... ,  An} and 2 numbers P, Q

I have to find an integer M between P and Q , such that, min {|Ai-M|, 1 ≤ i ≤ N} is maximised.

1 < N < P ≤ Q ≤ 10^6

in simpler words:

for each number, find the minimum absolute difference between this number and the array.
then out of all those minimum differences, find the **number** who has the highest minimum difference.

I have to do this in O(NlogN) or less.

I have tried the following:

- sort the array A (NlogN)
- iterate over all the numbers between P and Q and for each number find the minimum difference using modified binary search and keep track who has the highest difference - O((Q-P)logN)

I'm guessing there is some kind of math "trick" like using average I'm missing..

edit (add example):

for example if you have the array
{5 8 14}
and P=4 Q=9

the answer is 4,6,7, or 9.

lets look at the numbers 4-9

```
|4-5| = 1
|4-8| = 4
|4-14| = 10
```

so minimum diff for 4 is 1

```
|5-5| = 0
|5-8| = 3
|5-14| = 9
```

so minimum diff for 4 is 0

we keep going and find minimum diff for all the numbers and then we need to say which number (4/5/6/7/8/9) had the highest minimum diff (in this example 4,6,7 and 9 have 1 minimum difference which is max among all minimum differences)

Comment: what competition are you participating in?

Comment: @SalvadorDali This is not a competition question...
its a question from https://www.hackerrank.com (practicing  programming problems)

Comment: can you please provide a link to a problem?

Comment: @SalvadorDali https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-minimax
 but I think you have to sign up in order to see the problems in the site.

Comment: I think I don't get it. Can you provide an example with a small array?

Comment: @userunknown I edited and added example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to sort an array. Then you have to notice that your solution is either `P` or `Q` or some point `x[i] = (A[i] + A[i+1]) // 2`. Basically x[i] is in the middle between consecutive elements in the array (if this x[i] is between P, Q).

Because N is really small, this will run basically in O(1).

Comment: why the solution is x_i = (A_i + A_j) / 2 ?
can you please elaborate more?

Comment: please spend at least 30 minutes trying to figure this out (I already gave you the full solution, which can be transformed to < 15 lines of python code). If you will not be able to get it in 30 minutes, I will try to explain

Comment: for the array {1,6,13} and P=2 Q=11 what will be your answer?
the answer should be 9 or 10 but its not P,Q or any middle between consecutive elements

Comment: 9 (by division I meant integer division, sorry if it was not clear).

Comment: Thanks! In order to improve myself, can you please tell me how you got to the solution? what led you to think that way?

Comment: @Adam I draw a picture (1d line) Put dots there. Started to see where my point M should be it became clear that the number of possible positions is not infinite, but just a linear number in terms of n. Then I noticed that I also need to check boundary conditions.

Comment: @SalvadorDali I understand that the absolute difference between 2 points is the distance between them and I started with the 1d line and dots as well, but how did you get to think of the mid points? I think I'm missing something very simple

Comment: @SalvadorDali I can see why this is correct (any other distances but the ones created from mid-points would be smaller than the others) but I can't see what got you to think of that

Comment: Because n is really small this is O(nlogn +n ) . Complexity is not a constant but a bound on the growth rate. I don't dV, but I would rephrase would it should be fast.